# Can I use HashMaps in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, dictionary, hashmap

I cannot find much documentation about HashMaps in j2me. Does anyone have experience with this? How to create a HashMap?

> Map  map1 = new HashMap();

should work, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only the [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Hashtable.html) is available in [Java ME API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/).

Comment: indeed: http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr030/java/util/Hashtable.html to be exact

Comment: @hsmit: the `Hashtable` in my message is blue and clickable :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why is it so? Why is hashmap not available in j2me?